# ¿Cómo cambiar el símbolo de moneda para el estereotipo DINERO en OpenXava?

Tags: java, openxava, localización

Estoy teniendo problemas con el símbolo de dinero en una aplicación OpenXava. El símbolo se visualiza como $ aunque tengo el locale a Sudáfrica. Excel y otros programas reflejan R. Sin embargo mi aplicación OpenXava se empeña en reflejar $. He probado varios navegadores y sigo teniendo el mismo problema. También he establecido el idioma en Chrome y lo he subido al primer puesto en mis preferencias.

¿Alguien tiene alguna idea de dónde puede estar el problema?

Answer (score 1):

El editor para DINERO usa el locale del servidor para determinar el símbolo de moneda. Por lo que has de cambiar el locale del servidor que ejecuta el Tomcat. Si no es posible, puedes arrancar el Java que ejecuta el Tomcat con estas opciones:

```
-Duser.language=en -Duser.country=ZA
```

Deberías poder añadir estas opciones editando catalina.sh/.bat y dando valor a las variables de entorno JAVA_OPTS. Es decir, en Windows edita catalina.bat y añade la siguiente línea al principio:

```
set JAVA_OPTS=-Duser.language=en -Duser.country=ZA
```

O si estás usando Mac o Linux añade la siguiente línea al principio de catalina.sh:

```
export JAVA_OPTS=-Duser.language=en -Duser.country=ZA
```

En desarrollo, desde OpenXava Studio o Eclipse, puedes definir las susodichas opciones en el menú: Run > Run Configurations... > H= Arguments:
[image: Eclipse Java options for locale]